# Form.serialize() não funciona

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na qual tenho várias tabelas e *dialogs* usando o `form.serialize()`, mas essa em específico não está funcionando e não consigo achar o motivo.

**Formulário:**

```
<form id="formDialogOrdemServicoBuscaTopo">
        <span class="container">
            <span>
            <select id="selectOrdemServicoPesquisa" name="selectOrdemServicoPesquisa">
                <option value="numero">Número</option>
                <option value="cliente">Cliente</option>
                <option value="dataAbertura">Data Abertura</option>
                <option value="dataFechamento">Data Fechamento</option>
                <option value="equipamento">Equipamento</option>
                <option value="modelo">Modelo</option>
                <option value="nserie">Nº de Série</option>
            </select>
            </span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <span>
            <input type="text" id="inputOrdemServicoPesquisa" name="inputOrdemServicoPesquisa">
            </span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <span><button id="buttonOrdemServicoListaTipoPesquisa">Buscar</button></span>
        </span>
    </form>
```

**Código Javascript:**

```
$("#buttonOrdemServicoListaTipoPesquisa").off("click").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : "ordemServicoCadastroBuscaTopo.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data : $("#formDialogOrdemServicoBuscaTopo").serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#divListaOrdemServico").html('');
            $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                $("#divListaOrdemServico").append("<tr><td>"+val.id+
                "</td><td>"+val.nome+"</td><td>"+val.equipamento+"</td><td>"+val.marca+"</td><td>"+val.modelo+"</td><td>"+val.nserie+"</td><td>"+val.dataAbertura+"</td><td>"+val.dataFechamento+"</td></tr>"
                );
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert( jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

**Código PHP:**

```
<?PHP
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include("dbConn.php");

$tipoPesquisa = $_POST['selectOrdemServicoPesquisa'];
$dadoPesquisa = $_POST['inputOrdemServicoPesquisa'];

if($tipoPesquisa == 'numero')
    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE id LIKE '%$dadoPesquisa%'";

if($tipoPesquisa == 'cliente')
    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE tipo LIKE '%$dadoPesquisa%'";  

if($tipoPesquisa == 'equipamento')
    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE equipamento LIKE '%$dadoPesquisa%'";

if($tipoPesquisa == 'modelo')
    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE modelo LIKE '%$dadoPesquisa%'";

if($tipoPesquisa == 'nserie')
    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE nserie LIKE '%$dadoPesquisa%'";        

if($tipoPesquisa == 'dataAbertura')
    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE dataAbertura LIKE '%$dadoPesquisa%'";  

if($tipoPesquisa == 'dataFechamento')
    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE dataFechamento LIKE '%$dadoPesquisa%'";

if($tipoPesquisa == '')
    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` ORDER BY nome ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlSelect);

$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**Erro retornado:**

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: selectOrdemServicoPesquisa in        <b>Z:\web\ManutencaoNET\ordemServicoCadastroBuscaTopo.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: inputOrdemServicoPesquisa in     <b>Z:\web\ManutencaoNET\ordemServicoCadastroBuscaTopo.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>Z:\web\ManutencaoNET\ordemServicoCadastroBuscaTopo.php</b> on line     <b>35</b><br />
```

Comment: O que  obtem se fizer `var_dump($tipoPesquisa);` no PHP? como sabe que é o `.serialize()` que não funciona?

Comment: Não acontece nada com o var_dump. O erro do PHP me diz que as duas varáveis do form não são enviadas.

Comment: OBS: Todas os outros dialogs e $.ajax estão funcionando corretamente. E são iguais, apenas mudando os nomes das variáveis.

Comment: dizer que "$.ajax estão funcionando corretamente" e que `var_dump($tipoPesquisa);` "Não acontece nada" é contraditório... Como sabe que o AJAX funciona? se funcionar o var_dump deve retornar algo... se fizer `console.log(data);` na primeira linha da função `success` do AJAX e colocar o var_dump que sugeri, o que obtêm? (estou a partir do principio que sabe o que é a consola...)

Comment: Arriscando um palpite, diria que alguma coisa a mais do mencionado, nesse arquivo PHP ou noutro ao longo do fluxo da Requisição, está impedindo o funcionamento. Reproduzi seu código, removendo a interação com banco de dados, claro, e um `console.log(data)` no **success** como o @Sergio sugeriu, após enviar o formulário sem preencher nada, retorna `"SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE id LIKE '%%'"` como esperado. Pelo sim, pelo não, faça seu dever de casa como programador e trate aquilo que vêm do usuário. Assumir que o usuário é inteligente e não vai sacanear o sistema é pedir pra fracassar.

Comment: esse formulário está dentro de outro formulário?

Comment: Vá por partes, veja qual é o retorno de $("#formDialogOrdemServicoBuscaTopo").serialize() na consola antes de submeter por ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve capturar o evento submit de seu form ao invés do click do botão

```
$("#formDialogOrdemServicoBuscaTopo").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var dataSerialize = $(this).serialize();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Não esqueça de carregar a lib JQuery na sua página ok!?

**JS**

Alterei o **$.ajax** por **$.post** por este ser mais recomendado neste caso que você só irá carregar um objeto do DOM com um novo conteúdo. Mais pra frente você notará que o PHP retornará o conteúdo pronto pois o loop é feito no backend (PHP) e traz o resultado pronto para ser inserido na ***div#divListaOrdemServico***

```
$("#buttonOrdemServicoListaTipoPesquisa").off("click").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var dataSerialize = $("#formDialogOrdemServicoBuscaTopo").serialize();

    $.post("ordemServicoCadastroBuscaTopo.php", dataSerialize, function(data) {
        $("#divListaOrdemServico").html(data);
    });
});
```

**PHP**

No código PHP troquei os if's por apenas um switch, que é mais rápido e faz o código ficar de certa forma mais limpo, ficando assim:

```
<?php
    include('dbConn.php');

    // Faz uma verificação se a variável foi passada, em caso negativo o valor fica vazio
    $tipoPesquisa = isset($_POST['selectOrdemServicoPesquisa']) ? $_POST['selectOrdemServicoPesquisa'] : '';
    $dadoPesquisa = isset($_POST['selectOrdemServicoPesquisa']) ? $_POST['inputOrdemServicoPesquisa'] : '';

    $sqlSelect = '';// inicia a variável $sqlSelect como vazia para gerar erros

    // switch com as opções da variável $tipoPesquisa
    switch($tipoPesquisa){
        case 'numero':
            $sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE id LIKE "%' . $dadoPesquisa . '%"';
            break;
        case 'cliente':
            $sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE tipo LIKE "%' . $dadoPesquisa . '%"';
            break;
        case 'equipamento':
            $sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE equipamento LIKE "%' . $dadoPesquisa . '%"';
            break;
        case 'modelo':
            $sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE modelo LIKE "%' . $dadoPesquisa . '%"';
            break;
        case 'nserie':
            $sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE nserie LIKE "%' . $dadoPesquisa . '%"';
            break;
        case 'dataAbertura':
            $sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE dataAbertura LIKE "%' . $dadoPesquisa . '%"'; 
            break;
        case 'dataFechamento':
            $sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` WHERE dataFechamento LIKE "%' . $dadoPesquisa . '%"';
            break;
        default:
            $sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM `ordemservico` ORDER BY nome ASC';
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlSelect);

    $rows = '';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $rows .= '<tr>';
        $rows .= '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        $rows .= '<td>' . $row['nome'] . '</td>';
        $rows .= '<td>' . $row['equipamento'] . '</td>';
        $rows .= '<td>' . $row['marca'] . '</td>';
        $rows .= '<td>' . $row['modelo'] . '</td>';
        $rows .= '<td>' . $row['nserie'] . '</td>';
        $rows .= '<td>' . $row['dataAbertura'] . '</td>';
        $rows .= '<td>' . $row['dataFechamento'] . '</td>';
        $rows .= '</tr>';
    }

    echo $rows;

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código parece estar correto, se for pra chutar alguma coisa acredito que talvez você esteja com dois forms com esse id, ou uma outra div qualquer, e que nesse forma, não tenha nenhum valor selecionado ou não tenha esses campos.

Faça um teste, troque o id desse form para algum outro nome e tente novamente.

Veja também o que o serialize esta retornando, pois se for erro no javascript você pelo menos pode parar de investigar o php por enquanto.